# Misalignment between sections using res.cls class

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, cv, resume

I am making my Resume using the res.cls document class as found [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en). I have set the option `margin` in my `\documentclass` definition for the `\section` heads of my Resume to be to the left of the content. As stated in the documentation of res.cls "%   margin:   the section titles are to the left of the body text." In my "Professional Experience" section of my resume, I have typed raw content. In my "Technical Skills" section below, I have content in a tabular environment. Here is the problem:

[image: Content misalignment]

As you can see the content in my Technical Skills section is misaligned from that in the section above. Any idea how I may correct this?

Comment: Replace `\begin{tabular}{...}` with `\begin{tabular}{@{}...}`.

Comment: @Mico unfortunately that did not modify the alignment :( I changed `\begin{tabular}{l l}` to `\begin{tabular}{@{}l l}` May I ask what adding @{} should accomplish?

Comment: Please post the code you use to generate the cv. (The `@{}` particle serves to suppress the whitespace that's otherwise inserted at the left-hand edge of the `tabular` environment.)

Comment: @Mico I take it back! I changed that line on another section without noticing, that works! Thank you so much!! I learnt something too. Want to post the answer and I'll mark it as the answer? Or is that common knowledge and I'm just out of the loop..

Comment: The common wisdom is to not use this class anymore. It is old and (de facto, if not de iure) unmaintained.  Of course, if it works for your needs, go for it. But you are probably better off using another class or sticking with a basic class like `article` and setting it up yourself. The virtue of the second choice is that you have much more flexibility in the layout.

Comment: @Eric - Glad this got cleared up. I've posted my comment as an answer, per your suggestion.

Comment: @jon My original plan was to make my own template, but it seemed to be a large time sink with many caveats to overcome in terms of formatting. With a few tweaks I was able to get this one functioning the way I wanted.

Comment: I understand. CVs/resumes are a fairly big 'time sink', but they are also a good way to learn a lot of *TeX for what can be a fairly short document (i.e., learning about page layout, margins, tables, lists, bibliography, and so on). When you do have more time, you might consider starting on such a project. Keep `res.cls` for now, but (slowly) chip away at replacing it with something of your own design.  After all, I note that you are listing `LaTeX` among your 'Technical Skills'!

Comment: @jon Definitely a goal for myself when I find myself with a small amount of free time.. I have a solid grasp on most things in LaTeX (tables, figures, math etc.) but I would love to learn more about page layout and placement of different sections of a document etc. Do you have any recommendations on how to learn more about these topics? I find there's typically 5 ways to do the same thing, but 1 way is the best approach to the problem. It would be good to learn more about the foundation of LaTeX. - Thanks

Comment: Hmm, well the aesthetic side of things is often best considered by looking at books on typography. I also like to look at books and so on and think about what I like or dislike about their design choices.  The document `memdesign` (used to be part of the `memoir` manual is worth reading, too. Many of the ConTeXt manuals are worth reading too. For the 'foundations', besides the *TeXbook*, there's *TeX by Topic*; for LaTeX, the *LaTeX2e* file is crucial. For specific elements, the best thing is to experiment with various packages that deal with that element.

Comment: Cheers!  And of course, there's some nice layouts here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/8528. (Some may be too much: sometimes good design means being "quietly" good; otherwise you can end up looking like [this](http://xkcd.com/1273/) -- which really is what ["cool" graphic design resumes](http://tinyurl.com/ngf2d4x) look like....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a setup such as

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textsl{Communication Protocols:} & I${}^2$C, SPI, USB\\
\textsl{Development Tools:}       & Altium, GCC, ... \\
\end{tabular}
```

By default, LaTeX inserts vertical whitespace (in the amount of `\tabcolsep`; default value: `6pt`) to the left of the first column and the right of the final column of a `tabular` environment. To suppress this action, insert `@{}` (in words: "insert nothing") at the begin of the specification of the `tabular` layout, i.e., write

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
```